# Quintus V0.2.0 - Error when loading .tmx file

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a game in Quintus but when I try to load a .tmx level the following error shows up:
[image: Error in chrome]

This is my code from the app.js file
`window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var Q = Quintus({ development: true })
        .include("Sprites, Scenes, Input, 2D, Anim, Touch, UI, TMX")
        .include("ActionPlayer")
        .setup({
            width: 320,
            height: 180,
            scaleToFit: false,
            maximize: true,
        })
        .controls()
        .touch();

```
    Q.setImageSmoothing(false);

    Q.scene("level", function(stage) {
        Q.stageTMX("level1.tmx", stage); // line 17
    });

    Q.loadTMX("level1.tmx, tiles.json, tiles.png", function() {
        Q.compileSheets("tiles.png","tiles.json");
        Q.stageScene("level"); // line 22
    });
```

});`
Can someone help me? Current Quintus Version: 0.2.0

(I could't tag 'Quintus')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the same issue, and found the solution by trial and error.

In Tiled editor you have to set the layer format to XML.

To change this on an existing map, go to the "Map" menu item, select "Map properties" and on the left hand side select "tile layer format" and chang it to XML. Save the map again and voila, it works.